# In Asp.net Mvc hide field value can not be access

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model

I have one problem in my Asp.net Mvc 3 project. I am using data first approach
and strong type view. I hide one value on view from model as,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myfield1, new { style=" display:none" })
```

when I access this field value on java script I get null value or blank.

```
var abc= s("#myfield1").val();
alert(abc)
```

I will try like

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.myfield1, new{})
```

value will display on view.
I also try using hidden field but not work

have any issue or solution for this. I not display this field on view but this value required for further purpose.

Comment: I assume its `$("#myfield1").val();` (not `s`). And if its returning `null`, then its because your `myfield1` property is `null` - check the html your generating - it will be showing `value=""`. But if `DisplayFor()` is showing a value, then its a `ModelState` issue and you need to shown the code in your controller methods associated with this view

Answer (score 1):

For fields with display:none, it seems that val() does not work.

I bypass this behavior with attr():

```
$('input').attr('value',myNewValue);
```

Comment: Of course `.val()` works (try it!). And if `.val()` returns `null`, then so will `.attr('value')` - but you code is setting the value, not getting it

Answer (score 0):

because strongly typed html helper can't accessed when hidden  You can use this helper below instead of what you are using now
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.myfield1) 
this helper are used for store hidden value in strongly typed view

Comment: @ Naveen Ganeshe I try as you suggest but it does not work